# Setting text into a ContentView

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview

How do I go about setting texts/images into a Image and Content View I have in an xml?

I have something like:

tv.setText("Random Number: " + Math.random());
if (currentHour > 8 && currentHour < 22) {
            tv.setText("Random number:" + random + "%");

but I want the displayed text (tv) to be displayed in a new xml file, Result.

setContentView(R.layout.result);

Is there a way to gather information like the random number, etc..and have the results displayed in a new layout - Result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question makes no sense. Layout XML is static, it simply tells `LayoutInflater` what views to create, what properties to set, and how to link them all together.

If you want to change the activity's layout then call `setContentView(R.layout.result)` and then call `findViewById()` to find the `EditText` you want and then call `setText()` on that.